# Magento redirect to checkout after adding to cart

Tags: checkout, magento-1, redirect

I want to disable the shopping cart page. I mean that when customers add products to cart, Magento will skip the shopping cart page and redirects them to the checkout page to shorten buying process.

Is there any way to make it successful?

Please suggest me.

Comment: magento verision?

Comment: Want the redirection for  after cart or at any time if user hit checkout/cart/

Answer (score 0):

**Assume** that you have using **magento 1.x version**

and *assume that you does not want* access  `checkout/cart/` at all time.

For this case you can use [Magento Event/observer](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Using+the+Event-Observer+Method+in+Magento+1.x).

This is case use  magento event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index`

and from this event observer redirect to *`checkout/onepage/`* page

> ```
>   <global>
>     <events>
>       <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
>         <observers>
>           <redirect_to_checkout_from_cart>
>             <type>singleton</type>
>             <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer</class>
>             <method>forceToGoCheckoutPage</method>
>           </redirect_to_checkout_from_cart>
>         </observers>
>       </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>    
>     </events>
>   </global>
> ```

**Observer:**

```
<?php
class ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
    public function forceToGoCheckoutPage($observer){
        // force redirect to the checkout page
          Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'))
                ->sendResponse();
exit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final observer:

I've added a check for cart items because if cart cookie expires or you refresh checkout or success order page, magento displays error 500, too many redirects. If there are no items in cart you must redirect to another page like homepage.

```
  public function forceCheckoutRedirect($observer){

  $numberOfItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
  // force redirct to checkout page if cart is not empty
  if($numberOfItems > 0) {
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
    ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onepage'))
    ->sendResponse();
    exit();
  }
  else {
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
    ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('/'))
    ->sendResponse();
    exit();

  }

}
```